# VSCode Vim Search and Replace capture group

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

Edit: I just tried this in the VSVim extension in VS2019, and it worked as expected. 
I'm starting to think that VSCodeVim extension for VSCode doesn't handle captures properly?

I am trying to search my typescript file for a list of variables that have not yet been assigned an initial value, and set it to `= null`.

```
  private __requestor: Req;
  private __feedback: FeedbackObject;
  private __dueDate: Calendar = null;
  private __priority: number = NaN;
  private __bigTest = TestObject;
```

I am using the following command:
`:%s/(: [a-zA-Z]+);/\1 = null;/g`

I expect the output to stick `= null` on lines 1, 2 and 5, but instead it sticks a `\1`.

Expected:

```
  private __requestor: Req = null;
  private __feedback: FeedbackObject = null;
  private __dueDate: Calendar = null;
  private __priority: number = NaN;
  private __bigTest: TestObject = null;
```

Actual:

```
  private __requestor\1 = null;
  private __feedback\1 = null;
  private __dueDate: Calendar = null;
  private __priority: number = NaN;
  private __bigTest\1 = null;
```

Is there something wrong with my regex/search & replace command? It looks similar to the other S&R commands that use capture groups in examples I've seen, and I haven't seen any settings for "enabling" capture groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently in VSCodeVim, capture groups are recognized with `$1`, `$2`, etc.. rather than `\1`, `\2`, etc...

So, using this worked:

```
:%s/(: [a-zA-Z]+);/$1 = null;/g
```

Source:
https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4502

Answer (score 1):

Using more regex groups:

```
:%s/\v(__\w+)(:| \=) ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+);/\1: \3 = null; 

 % ....................... whole file
 \v ...................... very magic (avoid some scapes)
 (__\w+)  ................ first group (matches __word)
 (:| \=)  ................ second group, followed by : or space plus =
 ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+) ........ third group (matches CamelCaseWords) 
 ; ....................... followed by literal ;
```

OBS: What makes difficult to reach a proper result is the fact that line 5 has a different pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in VSCodeVim. I figured it out after scouring their Github page, for some reason they use $1 rather than \1 for their capture groups...